# write xml object to file using Actionscript 3 in Adobe Air application

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

So simple question and not an answer after a lot of search...Is it possible to do that? and how to obtain the values of my saveData function in the loadXML function? so far i do:

```
    public function saveData(name:String,date:Date,email:String,videoName:String,thumbName:String,comments:String):void{
        var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        myLoader.load(new URLRequest("assets/recordings.xml"));
        myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadXML);


    }

    private function loadXML(e:Event):void {

        xmlFile = new XML(e.target.data);
        xmlFile.prependChild(<recording>
                                <name>test</name>//??how to get the above values into this node
                                <email>test</email>
                                <date>test</date>
                                <filename>test</filename>
                                <thumb>test</thumb>
                                <commentst>test</comments>
                             </recording>);
     //how to write the xmlFile xml object to recordings.xml, thus updating it???
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's unclear whether you want to _write_ the `xmlFile` object to a file on the system, or you want to _read_ an xml file from the system and append it's results to the `xmlFile` object. Please explain this a little better.

Comment: i want to open the recordings.xml, and put a node like the one shown above so what i thought to do is load it prepend this node and then write it back...

Comment: i did the following:
...(to write)

    var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    bytes.writeObject(xmlFile);
    bytes.position = 0;        //reset position to beginning
    var file:File = new File(xmlPath);
    var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    fileStream.open(file, FileMode.UPDATE);
    fileStream.writeBytes(bytes,0,bytes.length);
   
    fileStream.close();

but it throws exception that the file is open!
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think you talk about [a `save` method of a `File` class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#save%28%29).

Comment: i did the following:
...(to write)

    var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    bytes.writeObject(xmlFile);
    bytes.position = 0;        //reset position to beginning
    var file:File = new File(xmlPath);
    var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    fileStream.open(file, FileMode.UPDATE);
    fileStream.writeBytes(bytes,0,bytes.length);
   
    fileStream.close();

but it throws the exception
any idea?

Comment: You use a `File` class in a wrong way. You should look on example to a `browseForSave` method.

Comment: In any case as a parameter in the `File` class constructor you should pass the path to your file, not an xml data (i.e. xmlPath).